# Cannot resolve symbol Manifest Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

Manifest file says there is a problem and "cannot resolve symbol @drawable/ic_launcher" and many others in manifest. Interesting that some like this  `android:screenOrientation="portrait" doesn`t declare error.

There is a piece of code:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.needtogo.Interface.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.needtogo.Interface.AutorizationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.needtogo.Interface.RegistrationActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.needtogo.Interface.OrderActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.needtogo.Interface.TimeActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="" />
    </application>
```

Comment: Check whether package is correct

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. You should check out settings.gradle. If you don't have this include: include ':app', you should add it and resync the gradle.

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you do have the drawable (ic_launcher is IN your res folder) then you likely just don't have your project building.

Try a clean/compile cycle and see if you can build your project.  The problem is that Android can't build the R class, and this is where those references are located.

Answer (score 0):

Place a image named ic_launcher by going res/drwawable folder and then clean your project it will work fine.